# Problem running a EF migration from a docker image to a PostgresSQL server from Github Actions

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, entity-framework, github-actions

## What am I trying to do (TL'DR)

Applying EF Core C# database migrations (create/update db/tables) to Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server from a docker image (created at PR) in CI/CD yml in Github Actions.

## The issue

I have gotten so far as to be able to see the postgresSQL server but when trying to connect I´m getting the following error

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 28P01: password authentication failed for user "***"

  Exception data:
    Severity: FATAL
    SqlState: 28P01
    MessageText: password authentication failed for user "***"
    File: auth.c
    Line: 418
    Routine: auth_failed
```

when running the following code in GitHub Actions

```yaml
deploy-development:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3

- name: Login to Azure
    uses: azure/login@v1
    with:
    creds: ${{ secrets.DEV_AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

- name: Login to ACR (Development)
    run: az acr login --name myAzureContainerRegistry

- name: Run Migrations (Development)
    run: |

    #1.  Get the image that I have already built in previous step.
    docker pull myAzureContainerRegistry/dbmigrator:${{ github.sha }}
        
    #2. Create a connection string to pass into the migration container 
    #    so it can run it against Azure PostgreSQL server.

    connection_string="Server=myPostgreSQLServer.postgres.database.azure.com;
    Database=dbToBeCreatedByMigration;Port=5432;
    User Id=MyAdminUser;Password=LegalWorkingPassWord;Ssl Mode=Require;
    Trust Server Certificate=true;"

    #3. Run the migrations. This is where the error accurse 
    docker run --rm \
    -e ConnectionStrings:Default="$connection_string" \
    myAzureContainerRegistry/dbmigrator:${{ github.sha }}
```

connection string format like this         `connection_string="Host=${{ env.DEV_POSTGRESQL_SERVER_NAME }}.postgres.database.azure.com;Username=${{ env.DEV_POSTGRESQL_ADMIN_LOGIN }};Password=${{ env.DEV_POSTGRESQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD }};Database=${{ env.DEV_POSTGRESQL_DATABASE_NAME }};Ssl Mode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true;"` doesn´t work either.

I have **verified** and made sure

**1.**
the **User Id and password are correct**. I changed them and hardcoded in the pipeline and also managed to connect to the server by using this psql command from my local computer using the same password.

```
psql "--host=myPostgreSQLServer.postgres.database.azure.com" "--port=5432" "--dbname=postgres" "--username=MyAdminUser" "--set=sslmode=require"
```

**2.**
that the flexible postgresql server has all the needed [GitHub Actions Ip´s](https://api.github.com/meta) setup as firewall rules. GitHub Actions could not connect until I added this

These are the ips `'192.30.252.0','185.199.108.0',  '140.82.112.0',  '143.55.64.0', '20.201.28.148', '20.205.243.168',  '20.87.225.211',  '20.248.137.49',  '20.207.73.85',  '20.27.177.116',  '20.200.245.245','20.233.54.49'`

**3.**
that the flexible postgresql server has the following settings

- has SSL/TLS enabled
- Connectivity method is Public Access (allowed IP addresses)
- Firewall rules to open it to GitHub Actions

**4.**
that the azure logs contain anything more info (they **don´t**) with the following query

```
let start_time = datetime("2023-07-28T07:42:08Z");
let end_time = datetime("2023-07-28T07:42:30Z");
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated >= start_time and TimeGenerated <= end_time
| where Category == "PostgreSQLLogs"
//| where Message contains "FATAL:  password authentication failed for user"
| project TimeGenerated, Message
```

**5.**
that there is anything funny happening in the docker file. It is basically like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myProject/aNuGet.Config", "."]
COPY ["myProject/myproject.DbMigrator.csproj", "myProject/myProject.DbMigrator/"]
RUN dotnet restore "myProjectDbMigrator/myProjectDbMigrator.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/myProjectDbMigrator"
RUN dotnet build "myProject.DbMigrator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myProject.DbMigrator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myProjectDbMigrator.dll"]
```

## My stack

- .net 7.0 Linux container image
- Burstable PostgreSQL Flexible Server in Azure
- GitHub Actions
- [abp.io](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core-Migrations) framework

**UPDATE**

It looks like abp.io is doing something (or wants me to do) that is causing it because this works with vanilla EF corer. I´ll update this question when I have some reply to [my support question](https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/5492/Something-is-missing-to-be-able-to-run-EF-migration-to-Azure-PostgreSQL-from-within-a-docker-in-Github-Actions)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error was that I was using a $ in the password and the **bash command running `docker run` was handling '$' as a variable being passed** in and skipped sending it and its following characters into the docker image.

Since GitHub Actions didn´t show me the values (user/pass) except in this format "***" I just assumed () that it was correct.